# css table overflow going off page

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to enable horizontal scrolling on my table. The table should be a certain width. I initially set it as 90rem to fit a desktop screen. However, if I use a laptop screen, the table spills over. I want to make sure the table is 90rem and if I move to a different screen, the horizontal scrollbar should appear.

This is what I'm encountering with the laptop screen. You can see the table spills outside.

[image]

This is my css below. .BP-Table-Content is pointing to the whole table.

```
.BP-Table-Content {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem !important;
    overflow: scroll;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 350px;
    max-width: 90rem;
    min-width: 90rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because it's parent HTML component width is not defined, put parent div / any component in a defined width or simply 100% not auto

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean a `<table>` because you have a `display: flex` in the css. If you are using a `<table>` then this might work. You also may use `vw` unit for the width of BP-Table-Content

```
<div class="BP-Table-Content">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

with css

```
.BP-Table-Content {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem !important;
    width: calc(100% - 4rem); /* 100% minus L/R margin */
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 350px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.BP-Table-Content table {
    width: 90rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.BP-Table-Content tr,
.BP-Table-Content tbody {
    width: inherit;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .BP-Table-Content table {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```